# Heuristics to find "surprising" mutual friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have the undirected friends graph of my Facebook friends, `G` i.e. `G[i][j] = G[j][i] = true` iff my friend `i` and friend `j` are friends with each other. I want to find "surprising" mutual friends i.e. pairs of my friends I normally would not expect to know each other. What are some good heuristics/algorithms I can apply? My initial idea is to run a clustering algorithm (not sure which one is the best) and see if I can find edges going across clusters. Any other ideas? What's a good clustering algorithm I can use that takes in a G and spits out clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my idea. Friendship is an edge. Surprising friendship is an edge, such that if you remove the edge, the distance between the two nodes becomes very large.

Comment: This seems like a good way to do it, but may not be practical if there are a large number of people and friendships involved as it requires calculating shortest path |E| times, with each potentially being up to |V| long, as such it may be good to define how distant a surprising friendship actually is. By setting an upper limit on how much distance is required, it is possible to set an upper limit on the algorithms worst case performance. Although, it's probably not much of an issue, so +1.

Comment: This algorithm is O(E(V+E)) i.e. for each edge, do bfs. Anything faster?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Wu Yongzheng can be tied to an existing network concept that is a robust and perhaps more sensitive measure, i.e. a quantitative take on *the distance between the nodes becomes very large*. This concept is **edge betweenness**. In this context one would compute an estimated version. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality and http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/betweenness.html.